Unity Build Visual glitch

I have two orthogrphic cameras in a scene, one is for to render 3d models(Env) and one is to render UI.
There's also world space canvas to render UI on 3d models.
Everything looks correct in editor but after exporting the ios build this werid glitch occurs.
I have assigned UI layer to UI camera and 3d models layer to main camera.
Also I have set priority of Main camera to 0 and Ui camera to 1.
Here's the video link : https://imgur.com/a/vWf0q8o,
Here's the Screenshot : Screenshot

I have tried to change the priority values and clipping values

Is this a problem related to code you've written? Please see the tag's excerpt: "Questions should be about programming with the game engine and not usage of the graphical interface. Questions about the usage of the graphics interface are off topic." - If this is an actual programming-related question, then please add enough code to create an actual [mre]
